# block routes when database unavailable (graceful "shutdown")

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm building a web server in nodejs which relies on redis, postgresql and mongodb. I store all the credentials in the google cloud secret manager, so I have to use asynchronous functions to get them. My code so far:

```
// Redis.js

const { accessSecretVersion } = require('./google_cloud/secret-manager')

const Redis = require('redis')

// initialize connection (promise because accessSecretVersion is an async function)
const initialize = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const redis = Redis.createClient({
        host: await accessSecretVersion('redis_host'),
        port: 6379
    })

    redis.on('error', err => reject(err))

    redis.on('connect', () => resolve(redis))    
}) 

module.exports = {
    initialize
}

// App.js

'use strict'

const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())

const Redis = require('./redis')

let redis

// try to initialize a connection
// then => it works!
// catch => it does not work!
Redis.initialize.then(redis => {
    redis = redis
    console.log('redis available')
}).catch(err => console.log(err))

// further on, other stuff rely on 'redis'
// if 'redis' is undefined, they crash, but I want a graceful "shutdown" of the functions

// here, the emitter relies on 'redis'
// the problem is, this code is ran BEFORE the redis connection 
// has established, so it returns an empty
// (when this code runs, 'redis' is still undefined)
const Io = require('./components/socket_io/emitter')(redis)
```

As you can see, on app.js, I try to create a redis connection. If success (resolve in redis.js), "let redis" is set to the redis connection. If not (reject), I log the error in the console.

The problem is that some other functions down this code rely on the redis connection, like socket.io-redis/socket.io-emitter.

**What I want to achieve?**

If the redis server is down, I want to send a global status code 503 (service unavailable), no matter what route is requested. The server should not crash but should not be reachable, because a lot of the functions in my server rely on data in the redis database, and without this data, I don't want people do do stuff.

This is probably not the best approach what I'm doing + is it a good idea to send a "global" error 503, or is it better to check for every distinct route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not do it at application level. ideally it should be handle by your infra.

at app level, implement a health check route, and do your logic there. eg: if mysql or redis is down, return 500 error. infra will see that error and stop routing traffic to that instance / server / container.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!